# How to set configuration values in SparkContext?

Tags: apache-spark

I have an object of type `SQLContext`. I know I can use `setConf` to set a configuration value for it, but if I want to set a configuration value for `sqlContext.sparkContext`, it doesn't have a `setConf` function available to set a value. So this doesn't work.

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2048")
```

Not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can simply pass `SparkConf` object to the context constructor.

Comment: What if I already have a `SQLContext` provided to me by Spark Job Server? I just want to modify it.